# IF/CASE statement within SELECT subquery

Tags: sql, if-statement, subquery, case

My script works almost perfectly, however the below part is the only part which is causing me problems. This part of the code works perfectly when a record exists in the FSFSR table however if no rows exists I want the result to be **1** rather than the MAX value from the SCFSR table +1 but everything I have tried doesn't seem to work.

```
(SELECT MAX(SCFSR.FSR_Num) FROM SCFSR WHERE SCFSR.FSR_Call_Num = T_Call_Num)+1
```

*Full code below:*

```
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRANSACTION
USE Tesseracttestv5

--------- DELCARE ARRAY ---------

DECLARE @RANGE TABLE(T_Call_Num INT);

INSERT @RANGE(T_Call_Num) VALUES (441925),(429021),(393852);

--------- SET CALL TO COMP ---------

UPDATE SCCall
SET
Call_Status = 'COMP',
Call_CDate = GETDATE()
WHERE Call_Num IN (SELECT T_Call_Num FROM @RANGE)

--------- INSERT SERVICE REPORT ---------

INSERT INTO SCFSR (FSR_Call_Num,    FSR_Call_Status,    FSR_Start_Date,     FSR_Complete_Date,  FSR_Last_Update, 
                   FSR_Symp_Code,   FSR_Fault_Code,     FSR_Rep_Code,       FSR_Solution,       FSR_User, 
                   FSR_Num,         FSR_Cost_Centre,    FSR_Site_Num,       FSR_Area_Code,      FSR_Employ_Num,
                   FSR_Prod_Num)

SELECT      T_Call_Num, 
            'COMP', GETDATE(), GETDATE(), GETDATE(), 'GEN', 'OPN', 0, 'Closed as part of database cleanse', 'JTY',
            (SELECT MAX(SCFSR.FSR_Num) FROM SCFSR WHERE SCFSR.FSR_Call_Num = T_Call_Num)+1,             
            (SELECT SCCall.Call_Cont_Num FROM SCCall WHERE SCCall.Call_Num = T_Call_Num),
            (SELECT SCCall.Call_Site_Num FROM SCCall WHERE SCCall.Call_Num = T_Call_Num),
            (SELECT SCCall.Call_Area_Code FROM SCCall WHERE SCCall.Call_Num = T_Call_Num),
            (SELECT SCCall.Call_Employ_Num FROM SCCall WHERE SCCall.Call_Num = T_Call_Num),
            (SELECT SCCall.Call_Prod_Num FROM SCCall WHERE SCCall.Call_Num = T_Call_Num)        
FROM @RANGE

COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

SELECT  ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
        ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage,
        ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
        ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine
END CATCH
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `COALESCE`:

```
COALESCE((SELECT MAX(SCFSR.FSR_Num) FROM SCFSR WHERE SCFSR.FSR_Call_Num = T_Call_Num)+1, 1)
```

If there is no record existed in table, this sub query get you `null`, `COALESCE` will return first non-null element in parameter list. So here it will give you 1 when record does not exist.

Comment: Did you missed `;)` in the first line of the answer?